# Sleeping Less with Merlín Magic suit?

Tags: infant, crying, swaddling

My almost 10 week old is not yet on a schedule though I’d like to be (first baby).  We just transitioned from sleeping in the rock and play to sleeping in the pack and play to try to get to a flat surface. Around the same week also took him out of the swaddle because he was fighting it. We just put him in the Merlín Magic suit. I had high hopes and  while he does fall sleep quickly he seems to wake up much more frequently. Rather than getting up every 3 to 4 hours to feed he is now getting up exactly every two hours. His extreme gassiness which he’s always had continues and usually starts about 4 AM. Has anyone else happen with this suit (more frequent waking) or have any suggestions what I should do? We are now up about 4-5 times a night and it’s just killing my sleep.

Answer (score 9):

First, sleep deprivation (a nightmare-while-awake) is a real problem for every parent with every new infant, so trying to get the baby to sleep more is a real priority for parents. So your desire is very understandable, and not to be brushed off.

I have no experience with the Magic Merlin suit, but I was intrigued by the idea of something needed to transition out of swaddling.

The Magic Merlin Suit is basically a suit designed to immobilize a baby (like swaddling) in an arms extended position with little freedom to move relative to being in a bag or just pajamas. I see a few possibilities.

Maybe the infant is overheating. It's easier to fall asleep but harder to stay asleep if a bit too warm. From the looks of it, I think this is very high on the list of "maybe's". Check the baby on his awakening for any signs of being too hot and you might have your answer.

Another possibility is that your baby fought swaddling because he wanted more freedom. For babies, it's important to be able to self-soothe by sucking on fingers/fists. Sure, babies sometimes startle themselves while awake by (in effect) striking themselves in the face, but they learn to control this. It's possible that your child cries while in the suit because of his restricted movement and/or inability to stick his hands in his mouth.

Try ditching the suit and not swaddling. If it's just a phase he's going through (sometimes babies go through hungrier phases), it won't make any difference. If it's the suit, he will sleep better without it.

<sub>My major concern about the suit is overheating. My second is restriction of movement. Babies need to move, explore their hands with their mouths, etc. Yes, the suit may dampen the startle response, but this reflex diminishes with time anyway. My third concern is the possibility of plagiocephaly (flattening of the back of the head), which is expensive to treat, if this suit is used too long.</sub>

<sub>I couldn't find the AAP position on this kind of sleepsuit, nor any safety certifications on it either. I recommend that you discuss use of this product with your pediatrician before use.</sub>